# In assembly, how do I store the input from the scanf call?

Tags: linux, assembly, att

```
input: .asciz "%ld"...

subq $8, %rsp
eaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
movq $input, %rdi
movq $0, %rax
call scanf
```

I want to store the input given from the scanf and modify it, and then print it using

```
call printf
```

How could I approach this problem?

Comment: You have already stored the input on the stack at address `-8(%rbp)`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Would I have to save it then in another register in order to modify it?

Comment: No, but it might be useful to do so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your input at `leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi`, then print out the value

```
leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
pushl %rsi          // or %rdi if i'm wrong
pushl $input
call printf
```

I think `eaq` meaning `leaq`